# Placing a tooltip on the left instead of on the right over a button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a tooltip of a button on the left instead of on the right.

On the left:

[image]

Toolbar:

```
$('#divToolbar').css({
        'top': '0%',
        'left': '0%',
        'z-index': '100',
        'position': 'absolute'
});
```

Tooltip:

```css
.toolbar-vertical-group > .adsk-button > .adsk-control-tooltip 
{
     left: 120%;
     bottom: 25%;
}
```

But on the right:

[image]

```
  $('#divToolbar').css({
        'top': '0%',
        'left': '96%',
        'z-index': '100',
        'position': 'absolute'
    });
```

```css
.toolbar-vertical-group > .adsk-button > .adsk-control-tooltip {
    left: -120%;
    bottom: 25%;
}
```

It gets cut by the edge of the screen. I tried to add some paddings or margins but that didn't seem to help..

The toolbar should be on the right edge of the screen.

Comment: A jsFiddle or snippet would help us to determine the problem

Comment: uhm... just use right positioning instead of left?

Comment: left: auto; right: 0; transform: translateX(-100%); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get some inspiration maybe. It is quite hard to determine what you want to achiev. **Edit:** maybe "How?" would be more fitting, than "What"

```css
.tools {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.tool {
  position: static;
  width: 80%;
  height: 17%;
  margin: 10%;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #FFF;
}

.tooltip {
  left: calc(100% + 5px);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
}

.tool:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}

.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 5px;
}

.right .tooltip {
  left: auto;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="tools">
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tools right">
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tool">
    <div class="tooltip">Hello there, i am tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```